# Objective C calling method dynamically with a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dynamic, methods, messaging

Im just wondering whether there is a way to call a method where i build the name of the method on the fly with a string.

e.g. I have a method called loaddata

```
-(void)loadData;
```

to call this i would normally call it like

```
[self loadData];
```

But i want to be able to call it dynamically with a string e.g.

```
NSString *methodName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"loadData"];
[self methodName];
```

This is a stupid example but i hope you get my point. I am using it for databinding classes that I am setting up for my IPad application. Hard to explain but to get it to fire I need to work out how to call a method with a string.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: +1 for clear, simple question!

Comment: The method I want to call is a function that returns an NSString.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can try something like

```
SEL s = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);
[anObject performSelector:s];
```

Comment: In this situation the method returns a value which is an NSString in one case. I get an error saying Lvalue required as left operand of assignment. This is my code: SEL s = NSSelectorFromString(@"getIDString"); [self text] = [boundEntity performSelector:s];

Comment: what is [self text],where you assign the value return getIDString.

Comment: `[boundEntity performSelector:s]` returns a value of type that does not match the type of `[self text]`. I think you need to set @property for text and call `[self setText:[[boundEntity performSelector:s]]]`.

Comment: performSelector may cause a leak because selector is unknown!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown/20058585#20058585

Answer (score 13):

You can use the objc_msgSend function.  It takes two parameters, the receiver and the selector to send to it:

```
objc_msgSend(self, someSelector);
```

You'll need to turn your string into the appropriate selector using `NSSelectorFromString`:

```
NSString *message = [self getSomeSelectorName];
objc_msgSend(self, message);
```

The method also takes a variable number of arguments, so you can send messages with any number of arguments.

```
NSString *message = [self getSomeSelectorNameWithManyArguments];
objc_msgSend(self, message, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
```