# Objective-C compile errror: expected expression before ‘SEL’

Tags: objective-c

I have strange compilation issue while implementing sth [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446883/objective-c-calling-method-dynamically-with-a-string) e.g

Works :

```
  [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(member)];
```

Not Working :

```
  SEL method=NSSelectorFromString(member);
  [self performSelector:method];
```

Compiler crying with:

```
methods.m:31: error: expected expression before ‘SEL’
methods.m:32: error: ‘method’ undeclared (first use in this function)
methods.m:32: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
methods.m:32: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

complete method:

```
 - (void)printArgs:(NSString *)member
{   
   //int val=[self compareIt:member];
    switch ([self compareIt:member])
    {
        case 1:
            //dynamically call method
            SEL method;
            method = NSSelectorFromString(member);
            NSLog(@"\n%@ is a object Member , with value: %i\n", member, [self performSelector:method]);            
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"\nWrong option :%@ \n", member);
    } 

}
@end
```

Please point me in right direction.(please note  I am new to Objective-C)

Comment: And what precedes this line, may I ask?

Comment: @raina77ow plz check the complete method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a C problem rather than an Objective-C one.  It doesn't like having variables defined within a `case` without having their scope constrained.

This should work:

```
case 1: {
    //dynamically call method
    SEL method;
    method = NSSelectorFromString(member);
    NSLog(@"\n%@ is a object Member , with value: %i\n", member, [self performSelector:method]);
}
break;
```