# How to make app run a method from a variable name

Tags: ios, methods, nsstring

I am making an app in Xcode and my goal is when a button is pressed a method will be run. The Problem is when the button is pressed the first time I want to change a variable/NSString so the next time it is pressed it does something else. By the way I have 375 different methods it could go to, depending on the variable name.

If you could help me I would really appreciate it.

I have not added all of the methods yet

My code is

```
//
//  Game.m
//  Trivia in a Jar
//
//  Created by Jayden Kelly on 12/11/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Jaydz Media. All rights reserved.
//
#import "Game.h"
#import "Categories.h"
@interface Game ()
@end
@implementation Game
-(IBAction)AnswerLabel1:(id)sender{
    Selected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Answer1.currentTitle];
    if ([Selected isEqualToString:CorrectAnswer]) {
        NSString *name = @"Question8Science"; SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(name); [self performSelector:selector];
    }
    else {
        [self Question5Science];
    }
}
-(IBAction)AnswerLabel2:(id)sender{
    Selected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Answer2.currentTitle];
    if ([Selected isEqualToString:CorrectAnswer]) {
        [self Question5Science];
    }else {
        [self Question5Science];    }
}
-(IBAction)AnswerLabel3:(id)sender{
    Selected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Answer3.currentTitle];
    if ([Selected isEqualToString:CorrectAnswer]) {
        [self Question5Science];
    }else {
        [self Question5Science];
    }
}
-(void)Prepare{
    QuestionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Question];
    [Answer1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",OAnswer1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Answer2 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",OAnswer2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Answer3 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",OAnswer3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
-(void)Question{

}
-(void)Question1Science{
    Question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What is the term used to explain the process of plant turning carbon dioxide to Oxygen?"];
    OAnswer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Transpiration"];
    OAnswer2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Precipitation"];
    OAnswer3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Plants don’t turn carbon dioxide into Oxygen."];
    CorrectAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", OAnswer1];
    [self Prepare];
}
-(void)Question2Science{
    Question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Metal Bronze is made by mixing Copper and What?"];
    OAnswer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Copper and Aluminium"];
    OAnswer2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Copper and Iron"];
    OAnswer3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Copper and Tin"];
    CorrectAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Copper and Tin"];
        [self Prepare];
}
-(void)Question3Science{
    Question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What is the symbol for Water?"];
    OAnswer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H2o"];
    OAnswer2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Co2"];
    OAnswer3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wa"];
    CorrectAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H20"];
    [self Prepare];
}
-(void)Question4Science{
    Question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"How many colours are in a rainbow?"];
    OAnswer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"6"];
    OAnswer2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"7"];
    OAnswer3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"8"];
    CorrectAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"7"];
    [self Prepare];
}
-(void)Question5Science{
    Question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What is the Largest Internal Organ in the Human Body?"];
    OAnswer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Liver"];
    OAnswer2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Heart"];
    OAnswer3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lungs"];
    CorrectAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Liver"];
    [self Prepare];
}
-(void)Question6Science{
    Question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Popcorn Pops Because:"];
    OAnswer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The water on the outside turns into steam and blows it up like a balloon"];
    OAnswer2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The there is a hole on the inside and when it gets hot it blown up and explodes"];
    OAnswer3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Microwave sprays a magic ingredient and makes the popcorn grow magically"];
    CorrectAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The water on the outside turns into steam and blows it up like a balloon"];
    [self Prepare];
}
-(void)Question7Science{
    Question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"How many Bones are in The Human Skeleton?"];
    OAnswer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"206"];
    OAnswer2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"207"];
    OAnswer3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"308"];
    CorrectAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"206"];
    [self Prepare];
}
-(void)Question8Science{
    Question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Cranium is also know as What Part of the Body?"];
    OAnswer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Head"];
    OAnswer2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Leg"];
    OAnswer3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Finger"];
    CorrectAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Head"];
}
-(void)Question9Science{
    Question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What part of the human body is the pupil located on?"];
    OAnswer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chest"];
    OAnswer2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Eye"];
    OAnswer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Finger"];
    CorrectAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Eye"];
}
-(void)Question10Science{
    Question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"How many calories does water contain?"];
    OAnswer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"897 calories"];
    OAnswer2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0 calories"];
    OAnswer3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"42 calories"];
    CorrectAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0 calories"];
}
-(void)Question11Science{
    Question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What is the melting point for Iron?"];
    OAnswer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1536°C"];
    OAnswer2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1537°C"];
    OAnswer3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1538°C"];
    CorrectAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1536°C"];
}
-(void)Question12Science{
    Question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What is the melting point for Metal?"];
    OAnswer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"660°C"];
    OAnswer2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"720°C"];
    OAnswer3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"870°C"];
    CorrectAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"660°C"];
}
-(void)Question13Science{
    Question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Approximately how many bird species do we have in the world?"];
    OAnswer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"50"];
    OAnswer2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"10,000"];
    OAnswer3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"15,000"];
    CorrectAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"10,000"];
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    Next = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"7Science"];
    CategoryLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", SelectedCategory];
    [self Question13Science];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Comment: Please post what code you have. If you have 375 possible methods, this is probably a sign of bad design. Instead try to use more parameters or conditionals in your methods to combine similar methods into one. no functionality should be coded in two different places.

Comment: I have added the code for you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446883/objective-c-calling-method-dynamically-with-a-string

Comment: I fear for the user that has to tap the button 300+ times to get the functionality they want from the button.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're just looking to conditionalize the events that occur upon button press. If so, you could try something like this:

```
- (IBAction)linkMeToYourButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (someCondition) {
        [self doSomething];
    }else{
        [self doSomethingElse];
    }
}
```

Comment: But I have 375 different methods that it could go to. Is there a way to do it like [self (vairableName)]?

Comment: @user2989426 Then you should rethink your design pattern. Instead of 375 different functions, you should make a single function (or a few) that take parameters to determine their behaviors.

Comment: @user2989426 I'm standing by what I just said, and I'm not recommending this, but for the sake of completeness, it is possible to do what you're proposing. Something like this:         `NSString *name = @"someName";
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(name);
        [self performSelector:selector];`

Comment: I did what you said but i gives me a warning saying PerformSelctor may cause a leak because its selector is unknown

Comment: @user2989426 No, you did what I said not to do.

Answer (score 0):

First, declare a variable to keep track of whether the button has been clicked already.

```
@implementation MyViewController {
    BOOL _buttonAlreadyClicked; // the default value is NO
}
```

In the tap handler, check that value, and call one of the two methods.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClickHandler:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if(!_buttonAlreadyClicked) {
        [self doFirstAction];
        _buttonAlreadyClicked = YES;
    }
    else {
        [self doSecondAction];
    }
}
```

if you have many possible actions, you could define some selectors:

```
SEL action1 = @selector(action1);
SEL action2 = @selector(action2);
```

and then in your click handler, call the appropriate selector depending on what you need:

```
 if(something) {
      [self performSelector:action1];
 } 
 else if(anotherCondition) {
      [self performSelector:action2];
 }
 // etc.
```

Your selector names have to match the actual methods you've defined,