# Dynamically call static method on class from string

Tags: objective-c

I have two strings:

```
NSString * className = "MyClass";
NSString * methodName = "doSomething";
```

MyClass class definition and **static** method doSomething also exists.

How can I trigger [MyClass doSomething] dynamically, from two strings?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(@"MyClass");
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"doSomething");
[class performSelector:selector];
```

This will get you a warning "PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown", which you can ignore like this (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown) for details):

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(@"MyClass");
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"doSomething");    

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
[class performSelector:selector];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 4):

You just have to use

```
[NSClassFromString(className) performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(methodName)];
```

here is also a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4446914/1141395)